# Unable to debug go application

Tags: go, delve

I am running go version 1.18.2 on an m1 mac.
When i try to run go run main.go it runs beautifully without any errors
but when I try to run `~/go/bin/dlv debug main.go` I get an error saying
`go build github.com/h2non/bimg: invalid flag in pkg-config --cflags: -Xpreprocessor`
I have tried running `export CGO_CFLAGS_ALLOW=“-Xpreprocessor” && ~/go/bin/dlv debug main.go` but to no avail.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide output of command, <go version>. How did you install dlv?
use below command 
GOOS=darwin GOARCH=arm64 go install github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@latest

Comment: go version go1.18.2 darwin/arm64

Comment: uninstalled delve and installed it again, didnt work